# Downgrade java from 1.7.0_91 to 1.7.0_79 on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, java

my ubuntu machine contains java 1.7.0_91. how to install java 1.7.0_79. how to Downgrade java from 1.7.0_91 to 1.7.0_79 on ubuntu

java -version output:

java version "1.7.0_91" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)